# Replace None with incremental value excluding values from skip list

Tags: python

I am trying to replace all `None` values in all sublists within a list to incremental numbers starting from 0 but excluding the numbers from the skip list. And there is one more requirement. If first element of a sublist matches to any other sublists' first element, then they all need to have the same value that replaces `None` in them if present. This is what I could try so far.

```
skip = [1,2]
a = [[1, None, 2], [3, 4, 5], [1, None, 7], [8, 9, 10],[11, None, 12]]
b = 0
d = {}
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i][1]==None:
        if b in skip:
            print("found b in skip")
            b = b + 1
        if a[i][1] in d.keys():
            a[i][1] = d[a[i][1]]
        else:
            a[i][1] = b
        d[a[i][0]] = b
        b = b + 1
print(d)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
found b in skip
{1: 2, 11: 3}
[[1, 0, 2], [3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 7], [8, 9, 10], [11, 3, 12]]
```

Expected output:

```
[[1, 0, 2], [3, 4, 5], [1, 0, 7], [8, 9, 10], [11, 3, 12]]
```

Comment: [1,2] are in skip list so next value after 0 is 3.

Comment: yes, as per jarmod's comment.

Comment: Will the sublists always be of length 3?

Comment: length of sublist will be a fixed number, that won't change. For simplicity, I have used length 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking up the wrong element in the cache in a couple places, and not skipping properly when the `skip` list contains consecutive elements. Here's the minimal fix with inline comments indicating changed lines:

```
skip = [1,2]
a = [[1, None, 2], [3, 4, 5], [1, None, 7], [8, 9, 10],[11, None, 12]]
b = 0
d = {}
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i][1]==None:
        while b in skip:          # Loop until skipped all elements in skip
            print("found b in skip")
            b = b + 1
        if a[i][0] in d.keys():   # Check for first, not second element
            a[i][1] = d[a[i][0]]  # Use first element, not second, for lookup
        else:
            a[i][1] = b
            d[a[i][0]] = b  # Indent so we only set cached value on cache miss
            b = b + 1       # Indent so we only increment b on new first element
print(d)
print(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVGxboMwEN35iqd0AdWqQtKqbaRMnSpV3TohDwaOYuHYCEOjqOq3UxsICWpvsM53fu/dO9entjR62/e2kjX2SGK24YHwmUvxbjQxbDhDsmW4Z3jw6dx49LcnhmeGeM1ZEs@deMN5kDqadZC78/snKEwDCanRCP1JoSIdiijaBXAhC4hE8iTm@73Hj1Ufx1IqQupxfsId5rjBmzE1Ot1KNfRqyiGUAik6kG7tGRPgKupG6jZcFabT@YV2FS0e@blT3CKeq@cB19xD8ruKTjaMdsMYLyVlFby9Qja2ZdCmhaXMOIVplgX75NRp5MlEyj3Ph6WR4Yy6ZmKDgDKm6i6GSNmrVS2500X9Sslbc2qvOncSsAZHgtHq5IRaZCIr3Rq/hOp8dbzjIK39f0HzX/ylkzprBhvupWPSdFy6C8avyKMpEVHf/wI)

And here's a more heavily modified version that is somewhat more Pythonic, using names, not indexing (when possible):

```
skip = {1,2}  # Use set instead of list; if skip is large, list membership check will be expensive, set will stay cheap
a = [[1, None, 2], [3, 4, 5], [1, None, 7], [8, 9, 10],[11, None, 12]]
b = 0
d = {}
for sublist in a:                      # Loop over values instead of indexing a over and over, C-style (slow and less readable)
    first, middle, _ = sublist         # Unpack to useful names (reducing risk of misindexing, and making more readable code)
                                       # Not unpacking in for loop itself because we need to reassign elements of sublist
    if middle is None:                 # Always use is/is not to compare to None
        while b in skip:
            b += 1                     # Use += to avoid repeating variable name
        if first in d:                 # No need for .keys(); "in d" has same effect as "in d.keys()" and avoids creating unnecessary keys view
            sublist[1] = d[first]      # Indexing needed for assignment to modify original list
        else:
            sublist[1] = d[first] = b  # Can populate cache and reassign middle value all at once
            b += 1
print(d)
print(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVPNbtswDL7nKYj2kmDeVrcbtqXoYehpwLBbT0FQ0BadCJElQ5STGkOfPSNVx1uBDKhOkkjx@yHVDWkb/M3xyDvbwR38LovrZ4BLeGACpgTWcyI0EBpwltMt2AZyrmVwGDdU5Htoqa0o8lYi9ZbqHRysc1AR0FNHnu1eErVevuaEg6ZhN0MBXa3KAn4FLynX6wJWNwV8KuCzbqfAFz19LeBbAeXVuliVU6S8Xq9nlZS5mhlV8DxrQgTuq8zLesAlnF2X8DOEDsKeIuzR9cT/qrXe0JP1G8CXDPQmbwq4f89pcARzduGQ7x0xQ5SHWDlazLR4YyOnAlprjBOSj8LsROkv/oPvUKxKAXqmpnfgsRUW80imrxU7Wt4pmdbyiU@REVvcabwNkSZgqIMZ0d@wLsW@BH1moKXEKPXNqSU2MblGulejEIMDgScyylOwmO3GAzlqySdWdqOwjGybUbMOiDZoeQb5uzvgwCpasj5KohcqUr0ObYeiSLb6dJJy2FopWClHnb3lK40VvLuD8j8adYwlLAVxH6wR/h1hUr17jDa7pp5PBYV@7pxCmeVZ0168UK8@7Gjg@eIWLjT7ArbIwFINqGmoTiDHHBnzLnLnMg@GOo48eu@plvnBOIDmwd7S4ZXA0d5VuZYhMqvMb33i8@M0pspq5PXSIm2PCm@Dsc0AIdqN9ehgapUuckzLN6Ddic2Cdo8eutD1DpOMG8oXzpqmqRhbn38ToPx0TBB8TWcaNuui9WluFuMGF8fjHw)

Either version gets the expected output from the question.

Comment: ShadowRanger, I just deleted my other questions which was related to this. Actually I had to keep track of multiple values, but got confused. Sorry for deleting it and not clarifying the question properly. Thank you once again for taking a look at it and providing your comments!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach to solve this, It's a bit lengthy but easy to follow and it's more generic:

1- `None` can be placed anywhere in the list from index 0 to the end.
2- (according to your comment) sublists don't have to be of length three.

I've put comments for explanation:

```py
skip = {1, 2}
lst = [[1, None, 2], [3, 4, 5], [1, None, 7], [8, 9, 10], [11, None, 12]]

# Filling a dictionary which groups sublists based on first item.
d = {}
for sublist in lst:
    first, *_ = sublist
    if first is None:  # No need to add to the dictionary because later, we won't traverse if the first item is  None.
        continue
    if first in d:
        d[first].append(sublist)
    else:
        d[first] = [sublist]


# A generator which yields correct next value
def increment_counter():
    counter = 0
    while True:
        if counter not in skip:
            yield counter
        counter += 1


counter = increment_counter()

for sublist in lst:
    if all(item is not None for item in sublist):
        continue

    first, *_ = sublist

    if first is None:  # No check is needed if None is the first item.
        sublist[0] = next(counter)

    else:  # None is not the first item so we need to traverse our dictionary.
        n = next(counter)
        for l in d[first]:
            for i, item in enumerate(l):
                if item is None:
                    l[i] = n

print(lst)
```

output:

```
[[1, 0, 2], [3, 4, 5], [1, 0, 7], [8, 9, 10], [11, 3, 12]]
```

This also works for lists like:

```py
[[1, None, 2], [3, 4, 5], [1, None, 7], [8, 9, 10], [11, 12, None], [None, 12, 5]]
[[None, 1, 2, 22], [3, 4, 5, 2], [1, None, 7, 8], [1, 9, 10, None]]
```